# How To Detect That Microphone Is In The Use Using C#

Tags: .net, xamarin, c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have one UWP application in which I am trying to detect if microphone is used by any application or not.

Here is the code to get the microphone from my system.

```
namespace CallDetector
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private MediaCapture mediaCapture;
       
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            StartMicrophoneStatusCheckTimer();
        }

        private void StartMicrophoneStatusCheckTimer()
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            await CheckMicrophoneStatus();
        }

        private async Task CheckMicrophoneStatus()
        {
            var microphoneDevice = await GetMicrophoneDeviceAsync();

            if (microphoneDevice != null && microphoneDevice.IsEnabled)
            {
                var msg = new MessageDialog($"Microphone device found: {microphoneDevice.Name}");
                await msg.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                var msge = new MessageDialog("No microphone device found.");
                await msge.ShowAsync();
            }
        }

        private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetMicrophoneDeviceAsync()
        {
            var microphoneSelector = MediaDevice.GetAudioCaptureSelector();
            var microphoneDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(microphoneSelector);
            return microphoneDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

How can I detect that microphone is used by which application (By using the UWP C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the API in Namespace [Windows.Media.Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices?view=winrt-22621), currently there is no API that can get which app is using the microphone. Just in case, I also checked Win32 [Audio Session Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-session-events), also couldn't get which process is using the microphone, it can only register and receive notifications of some specific session events.

Comment: I have also made some research for it. But I didn't find any helpful.

Comment: Could you monitor for any apps running that are attempting to or are using APIs used to record the mic? Here is a common API used to capture audio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa452431(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN